# likelihood that Redis SCAN Never Terminates

Tags: redis

There's this note in the Redis SCAN documentation:

> The SCAN algorithm is guaranteed to terminate only if the size of the iterated collection remains bounded to a given maximum size, otherwise iterating a collection that always grows may result into SCAN to never terminate a full iteration.

In a scenario where Redis is used to store sessions (so can be ever expanding), what is the likelihood that this happens? Is it safe to use SCAN for a full-iteration in production (for example to clear a group of keys with a given prefix)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent scan iterations taking too long, you can get the keyspace size before starting the scan and terminate scanning after you've scanned that many keys.